# Show a one to many Relationship in one Row

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2016

Im using Access 2016 and have two Tables:

Boxes(BoxID, create Date, delete Date, )

Boxcontent(content ID, Box ID, name, Content name)

Each Box contains exactly 8 content entries.

I would like to create a Query that outputs:

BoxID1, create Date, Contentname1, Contentname2, Contentnamex

BoxID2, create Date, Contentname1, Contentname2, Contentnamex

How do I do that in Access2016 ?